# mysql select order by primary key. Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a table 'tbl' something like that:
ID bigint(20) - primary key, autoincrement
field1
field2
field3

That table has 600k+ rows.

1. Query: 
   SELECT * from `tbl` ORDER by ID LIMIT 600000, 1 takes 1.68 second
2. Query: 
   SELECT ID, field1 from `tbl` ORDER by ID LIMIT 600000, 1 takes 1.69 second
3. Query: 
   SELECT ID from `tbl` ORDER by ID LIMIT 600000, 1 takes 0.16 second
4. Query: 
   SELECT * from `tbl` WHERE ID = xxx takes 0.005 second

Those queries are tested in phpmyadmin.

And the result is query 3 and query 4 together return necessarily data.
Query 1 does the same jobs but much slower...

This doesn't look right for me.
Could anyone give any advice?

P.S. I'm sorry for formatting.. I'm new to this site.

New test:

Q5 : CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable AS (SELECT ID FROM `tbl` WHERE ID LIMIT 600030, 30);
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tmptable); takes 0.38 sec

I still don't understand how it's possible. I recreated all indexes.. what else can I do with that table? Delete and refill it manually? :)

Answer (score 5):

Query 1 looks at the table's primary key index, finds the correct 600,000 ids and their corresponding locations within the table, then goes to the table and fetches everything from those 600k locations.

Query 2 looks at the table's primary key index, finds the correct 600k ids and their corresponding locations within the table, then goes to the table and fetches whichever subset of fields are asked for from those 600k rows.

Query 3 looks at the table's primary key index, finds the correct 600k ids, and returns them. It doesn't need to look at the table at all.

Query 4 looks at the table's primary key index, finds the single entry requested, goes to the table, reads that single entry, and returns it.

Time-wise, let's build backwards:

(Q4) The table index allows lookup of a key (id) in O(log n) time, meaning every time the table doubles in size it only takes one extra step to find the key in the index*. If you have 1 million rows, then, it would only take ~20 steps to find it. A billion rows? 30 steps. The index entry includes data on where in the table to go to find the data for that row, so MySQL jumps to that spot in the table and reads the row. The time reported for this is almost entirely overhead.

(Q3) As I mentioned, the table index is very fast; this query finds the first entry and just traverses the tree until it has the requested number of rows. I'm sure I could calculate the precise number of steps it would take, but as a maximum we'll say 20 steps x 600k rows = 12M steps; since it's traversing a tree it would likely be more like 1M steps, but the precise number is largely irrelevant. The most important thing to realize here is that once MySQL has walked the index to pull the ids it needs, it has everything you asked for. There's no need to go look at the table. The time reported for this one is essentially the time it takes MySQL to walk the index.

(Q2) This begins with the same tree-walking as discussed for query 3, but while pulling the IDs it needs, MySQL also pulls their location within the table files. It then has to go to the table file (probably already cached/`mmap`ped in memory), and for every entry it pulled, seek to the proper place in the table and get the fields requested out of those rows.  The time reported for this query is the time it takes to walk the index (as in Q3) plus the time to visit every row specified in the index.

(Q1) This is identical to Q2 when all fields are specified. As the time is essentially identical to Q2, we can see that it doesn't really take measurably more time to pull more fields out of the database, any time there is dwarfed by crawling the index and seeking to the rows.

*: Most databases use an indexing data structure ([B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for MySQL) that has a log base much higher than 2, meaning that instead of an extra step every time the table doubles, it's more like an extra step every time the table size goes up by a factor of hundreds to thousands. This means that instead of the 20-30 steps I stated in the example, it's more like 2-5.

Comment: Still reading, but quick note: LIMIT 600000, 1 - it means it selects only 1 rows starting row 600000

Comment: Missed the `, 1`. In that case, the difference between 1/2 and 3 could be caching. 4 is still a direct lookup whereas the others still require walking the index

Comment: I set cash memory size to 0 in mysql config, so the results are not cached.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a significant difference in the speed of Q2 and Q3. And why Q3+Q4 runs faster than Q2 ?

Comment: Combining Q3+Q4 I can get the same result that Q2 returns

Comment: I see what you mean now. Was the ID you used in 4 high or low (i.e. near the front of the file or back)? I am pretty sure MySQL seeks, but  if not, it could be location within the file. Otherwise, disk caching (at the OS level) could have affected it.

Comment: Also possible that it's just a failure of mysql's optimization, it's known to be sub-optimal in some situations.

Comment: in Q4 I used one of the ids Q3 returns. And Q3 returns 600001, 600002... Also it's a fresh install of mysql server. Just installed it with default configuration. And anyway... 1.6 second looks too slow for me. Am I wrong about it?

Comment: I just populated a test DB with ~1M rows, and it took 0.13, 0.12, 0.09, and 0.00 seconds (for Q 1-4, respectively). 1.6 seconds definitely seems suspiciously long, though my data also shows a gap between 1/2 and 3+4

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your answers. I will try to create new table and populate it with random data.. and maybe recreate existing table. I will post if I get any interesting results

Comment: General point: Use EXPLAIN on your queries to learn what they're doing. Q3 is faster than Q2 because it doesn't load the table into memory, just as Kevin points out in his answer. Q4 is fastest because it's much faster to jump directly to an indexed value than it is to walk a tree to the Nth value. There is no mystery of caching. It's just the query plan that's different for each query (except Q1 and Q2).